# Enable Session state in sharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, sharepoint-2010

I setup a test box computer with server 2008 (standard edition, not R2 and not hyper-v editing). I then installed SharePoint 2010. I was amazed how easy the whole setup went (the prerequisites  setup on the SharePoint disk made this process oh so easy – great install system). Really this was just so easy.

This test box is being used for testing Access web services. I am able to well publish access applications to this test server and Access applications publish and run just fine on the web SharePoint site through an web browser.

However, the only thing that does not work is when I launch a Access report. The error message I get back is

**This report failed to load because session state is not turned on.**

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I can’t seem to find the setting anywhere to turn session state on. Any hints or links on how to enable session state in SharePoint 2010 would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On [Todds blog](http://todd-carter.com/p) you can [find a post](http://todd-carter.com/post/2010/04/30/A-Session-State-By-Any-Other-Name.aspx) which explains how to turn on session state in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Todds blog does give an answer. In fact, a far more simple execute of the ONE command in SharePoint powershell fixed this:
 
enable-SPSessionStateService
 
The above then prompts for a database name to use/create. I just entered dbSesison but any meaningful  name can be used. Here. So, just the one command fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:
http://geekdeck.com/sharepoint-2010-this-report-failed-to-load-because-session-state-is-not-turned-on/

Answer (score 0):

Probably not in SharePoint  head over to the IIS configuration and see whether session state is enabled there. I am not aware of anything in the SharePoint forms (I did set up 2010 on the weekend) that indicates session state. And as session state on farms is an administrator action (state server etc.), maybe they simply did not activate it?;)

Comment: We are talking about ms-Access WEB services here. Keep in mind that all of my m-access application with code and forms runs fine via a browser to the SharePoint site. The ONLY exception here is the above error message when I attempt to launch a access "web" report. Those web reports are built in ms-access but they actually run under SQL server reporting services on top of sharePoint. So this problem hints towards SQL reporting services that ms-access Web services uses. It possible that the above error message is miss-leading me, but it bad error message then.